# .Net Maui JumpList like Indexing for Android and iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui

Is there a way to create a JumpList-like control on .Net Maui, that acts similarly to the contacts indexing control for Android and iOS

Reference of what I needed

[RecyclerView with Alphabet Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815425/recyclerview-with-alphabet-index)

[Indexed CollectionView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684272/indexed-collectionview-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find a solution to what I was looking for I decided to go ahead and create this from scratch and here are the results.

This is a SkiaSharp-based control that literally reads your touches, tracks what you are touching, and sends events that you can use to update your CollectionView...

Install Freaky Controls from https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

```
  <controls:FreakyJumpList
        x:Name="JumpList"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.5,0.1,0.7"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        AlphabetProvider="{x:Static provider:JumpListView.AlphabetProvider}"
        CharacterColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
        HasHapticFeedback="True"
        SelectedCharacterChanged="SkiaJumpList_OnSelectedCharacterChanged"
        SelectedCharacterColor="Black"
        Touch="JumpList_OnTouch" />
```

Add the JumpList control and then use it, there's a great sample that you can run and checkout!

Results:

[image]